# remove middle part of query from url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

searched on stackoverflow a bit, but nothing helpfull.

I want to do the following via htaccess.

I have this url:

```
 site.com/location/usa/ca/los-angeles
```

and I want this:

```
 site.com/location/ca/los-angeles
```

Basicly I want to remove the abbreviation of the country. Keep in mind, I have more then one country.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change all link like `/location/1/2/3` to `/location/2/3`.
Use in your : `/location/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+/[^/]+)/?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help me much because that url is generated in WP. Its actually a taxonomy url and want to remove only the first parent of the URL.

Comment: It's what i do with my rewrite. Or edit your question with more explanations.